# Retrieving Node Values from XML if it have 1 diff child name and rest are equal

Tags: php, xml

I had an XML file like this

```
 <report>
    <table>
      <columns>
         <column name="dateTime"/>
         <column name="userLogin"/>
         <column name="campaignName"/>
         <column name="adGroupName"/>
         <column name="changes"/>
      </columns>
      <row dateTime="Aug 13, 2013 11:56:34 PM" userLogin="hello123" campaignName="Search Exact Parts - 2012 USA" adGroupName="12 volt razor battery" changes="Text ad changed  Status changed from Enabled to Paused"/>
      <row dateTime="Aug 13, 2013 11:56:34 PM" userLogin="hello123" campaignName="Search Exact Parts - 2012 USA" adGroupName="Razor Quad Battery" changes="Text ad changed Status changed from Enabled to Paused"/>
      <row dateTime="Aug 13, 2013 11:56:34 PM" userLogin="hello123" campaignName="Search Exact Parts - 2012 USA" adGroupName="Razor Quad Tires" changes="Text ad changed Status changed from Enabled to Paused"/>
      <row dateTime="Aug 13, 2013 11:56:34 PM" userLogin="hello123" campaignName="Search Exact Parts - 2012 USA" adGroupName="Razor Replacement Battery" changes="Text ad changed Status changed from Enabled to Paused"/>
      <row dateTime="Aug 13, 2013 11:56:34 PM" userLogin="hello123" campaignName="Search Exact Parts - 2012 USA" adGroupName="Razor.com" changes="Text ad changed Status changed from Enabled to Paused"/>
    </table>
  </report>
```

My problem is i'm trying to read this XML file. Code I wrote is,

```
foreach($xml->children() as $secgen=>$value){
        foreach($value->columns->children() as $thrgen){
            $feilds[] = $thrgen['name'];
        }
    $data[] = $value->row['dateTime'];
}
```

This code is reading only first row value ie.," Aug 13, 2013 11:56:34 PM "

Even I tried in all possible ways that I know. But I cannot Retrieve the ways in correct way. If any one can solve the problem, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `xpath` to select the `datetime` attribute of all `<row>` nodes:

```
$results = $xml->xpath("//row/@dateTime");
```

see them all:

```
foreach ($results as $result) echo "$result <br />";
```

Comment: Thankyou. I got my problem solved. I was using $data[] = $value->row['dateTime']; instead of using foreach($value->row as $fougen){$data1 = $fougen[$feilds[0]]; }